# MethodError: no method matching setindex! when using DifferentialEquations.jl

Tags: julia

I am trying to simulate a multi-dimensional SDE with non-diagonal noise using the `DifferentialEquations` package in julia.
The drift function has the following form:

```
function mu(dx, x, param, t)
    dx[1] = -param[1]*x[1]*x[2]-param[1]*(x[3]+x[4])*x[1]
    dx[2] = param[1]*x[1]*x[2]-param[3]*x[2]
    dx[3] = param[1]*x[1]*(x[3]+x[4])-param[4]*x[3]
    dx[4] = param[2]*x[5]*(x[3]+x[4])-param[4]*x[4]
    dx[5] = -param[2]*x[5]*(x[3]+x[4])+param[3]*x[2]
    dx[6] = param[4]*(x[3]+x[4])
end
```

and the diffusion matrix is given by:

```
function sigma(dx, x, p, t)
    beta = p[1]
    kappa = p[2]
    gamma = p[3]
    zeta = p[4]

    dx[1][1] = -sqrt(beta*x[1]*x[2]/100)
    dx[1][2] = -sqrt(beta*x[1]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[2][1] = sqrt(beta*x[1]*x[2]/100)
    dx[2][3] = -sqrt(gamma*x[2]/100)
    dx[3][2] = sqrt(beta*x[1]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[3][6] = -sqrt(zeta*x[3]/100)
    dx[4][4] = sqrt(kappa*x[5]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[4][5] = -sqrt(zeta*x[4]/100)
    dx[5][4] = sqrt(gamma*x[2]/100)
    dx[5][4] = -sqrt(kappa*x[5]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[6][5] = sqrt(zeta*x[4]/100)
    dx[6][6] = sqrt(zeta*x[3]/100)
end
```

Simulating the ODE specified by the drift function works fine with the following code.

```
u0 = [0.96; 0.03; 0.01; 0.0; 0.0; 0.0]
tspan = (0.0, 300.0)
p = [0.08; 0.06; 0.04; 0.02]


problem_ODE = ODEProblem(mu, u0, tspan, p)

solution_ODE = solve(problem_ODE, saveat=0.1)
```

But when I want to solve the SDE:

```
u0 = [0.96; 0.03; 0.01; 0.0; 0.0; 0.0]
tspan = (0.0, 300.0)
p = [0.08; 0.06; 0.04; 0.02]


problem = SDEProblem(mu, sigma, u0, tspan, p, noise_rate_prototype=zeros(6,6))

solution = solve(problem, EM(), dt=0.01, adaptive=false)
```

It does not work and gives the following error and Stacktrace:

```
MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Int64)

Stacktrace:
  [1] sigma(dx::Matrix{Float64}, x::Vector{Float64}, p::Vector{Float64}, t::Float64)
    @ Main ~/masterthesis/two_variant_model/own_simulation/final_simulation.ipynb:7
  [2] perform_step!(integrator::StochasticDiffEq.SDEIntegrator{EM{true}, true, Vector{Float64}, Float64, Float64, Float64, Vector{Float64}, Float64, Float64, Float64, NoiseProcess{Float64, 2, Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_DIST), typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_BRIDGE), true, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, RSWM{Float64}, Nothing, RandomNumbers.Xorshifts.Xoroshiro128Plus}, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, RODESolution{Float64, 2, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Nothing, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, NoiseProcess{Float64, 2, Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_DIST), typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_BRIDGE), true, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, RSWM{Float64}, Nothing, RandomNumbers.Xorshifts.Xoroshiro128Plus}, SDEProblem{Vector{Float64}, Tuple{Float64, Float64}, true, Vector{Float64}, Nothing, SDEFunction{true, typeof(mu), typeof(sigma), LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, typeof(sigma), Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, Matrix{Float64}}, EM{true}, StochasticDiffEq.LinearInterpolationData{Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Vector{Float64}}, DiffEqBase.DEStats}, StochasticDiffEq.EMCache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}, SDEFunction{true, typeof(mu), typeof(sigma), LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, typeof(sigma), Nothing, StochasticDiffEq.SDEOptions{Float64, Float64, PIController{Float64}, typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_NORM), Nothing, CallbackSet{Tuple{}, Tuple{}}, typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_ISOUTOFDOMAIN), typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_PROG_MESSAGE), typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_UNSTABLE_CHECK), DataStructures.BinaryHeap{Float64, DataStructures.FasterForward}, DataStructures.BinaryHeap{Float64, DataStructures.FasterForward}, Nothing, Nothing, Int64, Float64, Float64, Float64, Tuple{}, Tuple{}, Tuple{}}, Nothing, Float64, Nothing, Nothing}, cache::StochasticDiffEq.EMCache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}})
    @ StochasticDiffEq ~/.julia/packages/StochasticDiffEq/Wl3hr/src/perform_step/low_order.jl:40
  [3] solve!(integrator::StochasticDiffEq.SDEIntegrator{EM{true}, true, Vector{Float64}, Float64, Float64, Float64, Vector{Float64}, Float64, Float64, Float64, NoiseProcess{Float64, 2, Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_DIST), typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_BRIDGE), true, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, RSWM{Float64}, Nothing, RandomNumbers.Xorshifts.Xoroshiro128Plus}, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, RODESolution{Float64, 2, Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Nothing, Nothing, Vector{Float64}, NoiseProcess{Float64, 2, Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_DIST), typeof(DiffEqNoiseProcess.INPLACE_WHITE_NOISE_BRIDGE), true, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, ResettableStacks.ResettableStack{Tuple{Float64, Vector{Float64}, Nothing}, true}, RSWM{Float64}, Nothing, RandomNumbers.Xorshifts.Xoroshiro128Plus}, SDEProblem{Vector{Float64}, Tuple{Float64, Float64}, true, Vector{Float64}, Nothing, SDEFunction{true, typeof(mu), typeof(sigma), LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, typeof(sigma), Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, Matrix{Float64}}, EM{true}, StochasticDiffEq.LinearInterpolationData{Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Vector{Float64}}, DiffEqBase.DEStats}, StochasticDiffEq.EMCache{Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}, SDEFunction{true, typeof(mu), typeof(sigma), LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, typeof(SciMLBase.DEFAULT_OBSERVED), Nothing}, typeof(sigma), Nothing, StochasticDiffEq.SDEOptions{Float64, Float64, PIController{Float64}, typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_NORM), Nothing, CallbackSet{Tuple{}, Tuple{}}, typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_ISOUTOFDOMAIN), typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_PROG_MESSAGE), typeof(DiffEqBase.ODE_DEFAULT_UNSTABLE_CHECK), DataStructures.BinaryHeap{Float64, DataStructures.FasterForward}, DataStructures.BinaryHeap{Float64, DataStructures.FasterForward}, Nothing, Nothing, Int64, Float64, Float64, Float64, Tuple{}, Tuple{}, Tuple{}}, Nothing, Float64, Nothing, Nothing})
    @ StochasticDiffEq ~/.julia/packages/StochasticDiffEq/Wl3hr/src/solve.jl:611
  [4] #__solve#100
    @ ~/.julia/packages/StochasticDiffEq/Wl3hr/src/solve.jl:7 [inlined]
  [5] #solve_call#39
    @ ~/.julia/packages/DiffEqBase/U3LtB/src/solve.jl:155 [inlined]
  [6] #solve_up#41
    @ ~/.julia/packages/DiffEqBase/U3LtB/src/solve.jl:182 [inlined]
  [7] #solve#40
    @ ~/.julia/packages/DiffEqBase/U3LtB/src/solve.jl:168 [inlined]
  [8] top-level scope
    @ ~/masterthesis/two_variant_model/own_simulation/final_simulation.ipynb:1
  [9] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [10] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1116
 [11] #invokelatest#2
    @ ./essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
 [12] invokelatest
    @ ./essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
 [13] (::VSCodeServer.var"#160#161"{VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments, String})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode-server/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.6.17/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/serve_notebook.jl:19
 [14] withpath(f::VSCodeServer.var"#160#161"{VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments, String}, path::String)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode-server/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.6.17/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/repl.jl:184
 [15] notebook_runcell_request(conn::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.JSONRPCEndpoint{Base.PipeEndpoint, Base.PipeEndpoint}, params::VSCodeServer.NotebookRunCellArguments)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode-server/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.6.17/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/serve_notebook.jl:13
 [16] dispatch_msg(x::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.JSONRPCEndpoint{Base.PipeEndpoint, Base.PipeEndpoint}, dispatcher::VSCodeServer.JSONRPC.MsgDispatcher, msg::Dict{String, Any})
    @ VSCodeServer.JSONRPC ~/.vscode-server/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.6.17/scripts/packages/JSONRPC/src/typed.jl:67
 [17] serve_notebook(pipename::String, outputchannel_logger::Base.CoreLogging.SimpleLogger; crashreporting_pipename::String)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode-server/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.6.17/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/serve_notebook.jl:136
 [18] top-level scope
    @ ~/.vscode-server/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.6.17/scripts/notebook/notebook.jl:32
 [19] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:384
 [20] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
    @ Base ./client.jl:285
 [21] _start()
    @ Base ./client.jl:485
```

Since this is my first time using julia, I would really appreciate any idea how to solve that issue and simulate the SDE.

Another question would be if anyone knows whether there is a way to tell the integration algorithm that the simulated process (the solution of the SDE) shall stay positive. My only idea there was to use the integrator interface to perform integration step by step and check it after every step, but maybe someone knows whether there isd a built-in solution for that.

But the first problem is much more important.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to my problem, which was just me being annoyingly unaware of the different syntaxes to access elements in matrices in julia and python.
Changing the diffusion function to:

```
function sigma(dx, x, p, t)
    beta = p[1]
    kappa = p[2]
    gamma = p[3]
    zeta = p[4]

    dx[1, 1] = -sqrt(beta*x[1]*x[2]/100)
    dx[1, 2] = -sqrt(beta*x[1]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[2, 1] = sqrt(beta*x[1]*x[2]/100)
    dx[2, 3] = -sqrt(gamma*x[2]/100)
    dx[3, 2] = sqrt(beta*x[1]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[3, 6] = -sqrt(zeta*x[3]/100)
    dx[4, 4] = sqrt(kappa*x[5]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[4, 5] = -sqrt(zeta*x[4]/100)
    dx[5, 4] = sqrt(gamma*x[2]/100)
    dx[5, 4] = -sqrt(kappa*x[5]*(x[3]+x[4])/100)
    dx[6, 5] = sqrt(zeta*x[4]/100)
    dx[6, 6] = sqrt(zeta*x[3]/100)
end
```

solved the problem.

But then the second question got more important since I now get domain errors, when there appear some negative values.
Solved this as well by using integrator intferace to check after each step.
There is a built-in `isoutofdomain` option or one could use callback-function `PositiveDomain`, but this just ensures non-negativity up to an set tolerance, which still gives domain errors.

Comment: Are you sure that with the chosen parameter values the equation is guaranteed to have a positive solution? That is not the case for many chemical langevin equations, and this looks to be one. In which case, you can define the solution via the reflection, i.e. abs in the sqrt.

Comment: I am quite certain that it should stay positive. It is a closed population and the parameters as well as all states are less than 1, so it should stay positive at any time. Simulating the ODE-system supports that as well.
For now I am using `isoutofdomain` and for the slightly negative values that can nonetheless occur I added a `abs(0,x[.])` at every state, which works. But I would more like to really keep states positive at any time.

Comment: `u' = -sqrt(u)` hits zero in finite time. The linear SDE `du = -ax dt + bx dW` is guaranteed to have a positive solution, but  `du = -ax dt + sqrt(bx) dW` is not. Since your model seems more like the latter, I'm not convinced.

Comment: I got the SDE by approximating a non-negative discrete process with diffusion. The overall goal is to model a two-variant SIR-model with SDEs. Normally the way I derived it should ensure that the state space is `[0,1]`. 
I know this is not a good or intuitive explanation by now, but I would recommend the following paper [link](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/1882/) for a deeper insight on the mathematical derivation of the SDEs.